# Binding Click events for Dynamically added Table Rows in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, dynamic-tables, event-binding

Problem Statement:
I have a table with `thead` created statically, and 'tr/td' inside the `tbody` created dynamically. What I have to achieve is that when the user clicks anywhere on the table, I need to get the `val()` of the first column of the row which was clicked.

To test this I am binding a click event using `on` to the parent element class, i.e. class for `tbody`. And, I am trying to update the text in the First column `td:first` of the clicked row, e.g. `clicked`.

However, somehow the events are not being caught. Here is the extract from the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cd68m40/2/).

HTML:

```
<table class="table" id="table-id">
    <thead>
        <tr class="table-header">
            <th class="edit">Edit</th>
            <th class="name">Name</th>
            <th class="status">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-body" id="table-body-id">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

TABLE CREATION

```
var container = $('.table-body');
['A', 'B'].forEach(function(index){
    $('<tr>', {class: 'table-row', id: 'table-row-id-'+index}).appendTo(container);
    $('<td />', {class: 'edit', id: 'edit-id-'+index, value: index}).appendTo(container);
    $('<td />', {class: 'name', id: 'name-id-'+index, text: 'Mr. '+index}).appendTo(container);
    $('<td />', {class: 'status', id: 'status-'+index, text: 'MSc'}).appendTo(container);
    $('</tr>').appendTo(container);
});
```

BINDING CLICK EVENT

```
$("#table-body-id").on("click", "tr", function(){
    alert($(this).find('td:first').val());
    $(this).find('td:first').text('clicked');
});
```

I have looked at plethora of threads on stack-overflow and after that I wrote the above code. One [working JS-Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/4wa5kfpz/1/).

However, it is not working for the code that I have written above. Could somehow please point me out as to why is not working and how to fix it?

Comment: Not sure if it's a C+P error, but your javascript accesses `#table-body-id` and your table has an id of `table-id`.

Answer (score 4):

Your appends were all messed up. Here is your code corrected/working.

```
var container = $('.table-body');
//Create an empty container
var $trs = $();
['A', 'B'].forEach(function(index) {
    //Create TR and append TDs to it
    var $tr = $('<tr/>', {class: 'table-row', id: 'table-row-id-'+index});
    $tr.append(
        $('<td />', {class: 'edit', id: 'edit-id-'+index, value: index}).
        add($('<td />', {class: 'name', id: 'name-id-'+index, text: 'Mr. '+index})).
        add($('<td />', {class: 'status', id: 'status-'+index, text: 'MSc'}))
    );
    //Add each tr to the container
    $trs = $trs.add($tr);
});

//Append all TRs to the container.
container.append($trs);

$(".table-body").on('click', 'tr', function() {
    alert( 'Clicked row '+ ($(this).index()+1) );
    //Use .text() as td doesn't have method .val()
    //Empty first time as the td:first has no text until clicked.
    alert( $(this).find('td:first').text() );
    $(this).find('td:first').text('clicked');
});
```

[**A demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4cd68m40/3/)

Comment: Awesome. That worked. :-)
Thanks a zillion. Now I know that I should check my HTML. Just seeing it rendered as expected may not be right. :-)

Comment: Why wouldn't I? That's perfect. :-)
If you are talking about voting-up the answer, somehow I need '15 reputation' for my vote to be publicly visible. I am fairly new to SO. :-(

Answer (score 2):

It is not ideal to attach click events through the body, but in some occasions I do this and it works great.

```
$("body").on("click", "#table-body-id tr", function(){
    alert($(this));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, unfortunately, that didn't work.

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly with the latest version of jQuery!