# How would I add an onclick event for a table row. ex: if the decline button is pressed, that rows background turns red

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, modal-dialog

The snippet does not work for the code. I am using Json to import the table data to be displayed by html. Within the table row there is a modal button, that when clicked a modal view popups with two more buttons(approve and disapprove). What I need to happen is when clicking approve or disapprove, the row that the button is correlated to is edited(if approved, row is removed from table view. if disapproved rows background color turns red.)

```css
html{
            font:0.75em/1.5 sans-serif;
            color:#333;
            background-color:#fff;
            padding:1em;
        }

        /* Tables */
table{
    width:100%;
            margin-bottom:1em;
            border-collapse: collapse;
   border: 1px;
        }
th{
    font-weight:bold;
            background-color:#ddd;
        }
        
td{
    padding:0.5em;
            border:1px solid black;
   
        }
  
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ddd;
 
}
  
a.button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    appearance: button;

    text-decoration: none;
    color: initial;
}  

@font-face {
  font-family: 'ios7-icon';
  src: url("//ios7-icon-font-demo.herokuapp.com/fonts/ios7-icon.woff") format("woff"), url("//ios7-icon-font-demo.herokuapp.com/fonts/ios7-icon.ttf") format("ttf");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue' !important;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #007aff;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

section {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
section p {
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}



button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
   background: LightBlue; 
  color: #007aff;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  /* &:nth-child(even){ */
   /* background: white; */
  /* } */
  /*  &:last-child {
      border-color: red;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }*/
}
button:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
button.button-border {
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 12px 8px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #007aff;
}
 button.button-border:hover { 
   background: #007aff; 
   color: #ffffff; 
  text-decoration: none; 
 } 
 button.button-success { 
  /color: #4dd865; */
   border-color: #4dd865; 
 } 
 button.button-success:hover { 
   background: #4dd865; 
 } 
 button.button-error { 
   color: #ff3b30; 
  border-color: #ff3b30; 
 } 
 button.button-error:hover { 
   background: #ff3b30; 
 } 

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 430px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: -150px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 9999px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.modal.active {
  display: block;
}
.modal header {
  position: relative;
}
.modal h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
.modal .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.pull-right {
  float: right;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-family: circle;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: inherit;
  -webkit-text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  -moz-text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  -ms-text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  -o-text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
}
```

```html
<html>
       
    <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tablestyle.css">
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="datasource/people.json"> </script>

<script>

 $(function() {

   var people = [];

   $.getJSON('datasource/people.json', function(data) {
       $.each(data.person, function(i, f) {
          var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td><button class='button-border toggleModal'><span class='icon'></span> Timesheet Approval</button></td>" + "<td>" + f.lastName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.job + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.roll + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.hours + "</td>" + " </tr>"
    $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");

        $('#userdata').on('click', '.toggleModal',  function (e) {
             $('.modal').toggleClass('active');

                        });
                });

  });

});
</script>

<body>

<table id="userdata" rules="groups" style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <thead>

                <tr>
                        <th> </th>
                        <th>EmployeeNum</th>
                        <th>EmployeeName</th>
                        <th>ChargeNum</th>
                        <th>Hours</th>
                </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>

        </tbody>
</table>

 <div class="modal">

    <header>
     
  <button class="close toggleModal">Close</button>
    </header>

    <section>
      <p>To approve the timesheet and submit it to WAM press "Approve", to decline the timesheet for later viewing press "Disapprove"</p>
    </section>

    <button class="button-border button-success toggleModal">
      <span class="icon"></span> Approve </button>

    <button class="button-border button-error pull-right toggleModal">
      <span class="icon">< </span> Disapprove </button>
                <!-- <script> $(docuemnt).ready(function(){ -->
                        <!-- var rowCount = $('table#tableId tr:#a').index() + 1; -->
                        <!-- $("#a").style.color = "red"}); -->
                        <!-- </script> -->

  </div>


  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

```
{
  "person": [
   {
       "firstName": " ",
       "lastName": "Kent",
       "job": "Reporter",
       "roll": 20,
       "hours":10
   },
   {
       "firstName": " ",
       "lastName": "Wayne",
       "job": "Playboy",
       "roll": 30,
       "hours":20
   },
    {
    "firstName": " ",
    "lastName": "Scott",
    "job": "PaperMan",
    "roll": 20,
    "hours": 40
        }
   ]
}
```

~

Comment: It is all about context! when user clicks you should `bind(this)`with context to send the row context to the modal and then trigger with jquery based on the inherited context https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362761/binding-click-events-for-dynamically-added-table-rows-in-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/qwyjkcrr/

```js
var people = [];
var data = {
  "person": [
   {
       "firstName": " ",
       "lastName": "Kent",
       "job": "Reporter",
       "roll": 20,
       "hours":10
   },
   {
       "firstName": " ",
       "lastName": "Wayne",
       "job": "Playboy",
       "roll": 30,
       "hours":20
   },
    {
    "firstName": " ",
    "lastName": "Scott",
    "job": "PaperMan",
    "roll": 20,
    "hours": 40
        }
   ]
};

var row = 0;

$.each(data.person, function(i, f) {
  var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td><button class='button-border toggleModal toggleModalFromTable'><span class='icon'></span> Timesheet Approval</button></td>" + "<td>" + f.lastName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.job + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.roll + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.hours + "</td>" + " </tr>"
  $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
  $('#userdata').on('click', '.toggleModalFromTable',  function (e) {
   row = $(this).closest('tr').index() + 1;
    $('.modal').toggleClass('active');
 });
});

$('.approve').click(function(){
  $('.modal').toggleClass('active');
   $('table tbody tr:nth-child(' + row + ')').remove();
});

$('.disapprove').click(function(){
 $('.modal').toggleClass('active');
  $('table tbody tr:nth-child(' + row + ')').css({
   'background': 'red'
  });
});
```

```css
html{
            font:0.75em/1.5 sans-serif;
            color:#333;
            background-color:#fff;
            padding:1em;
        }

        /* Tables */
table{
    width:100%;
            margin-bottom:1em;
            border-collapse: collapse;
   border: 1px;
        }
th{
    font-weight:bold;
            background-color:#ddd;
        }
        
td{
    padding:0.5em;
            border:1px solid black;
   
        }
  
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ddd;
 
}
  
a.button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    appearance: button;

    text-decoration: none;
    color: initial;
}  

@font-face {
  font-family: 'ios7-icon';
  src: url("//ios7-icon-font-demo.herokuapp.com/fonts/ios7-icon.woff") format("woff"), url("//ios7-icon-font-demo.herokuapp.com/fonts/ios7-icon.ttf") format("ttf");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue' !important;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #007aff;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

section {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
section p {
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}



button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
   background: LightBlue; 
  color: #007aff;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  /* &:nth-child(even){ */
   /* background: white; */
  /* } */
  /*  &:last-child {
      border-color: red;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }*/
}
button:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
button.button-border {
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 12px 8px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #007aff;
}
 button.button-border:hover { 
   background: #007aff; 
   color: #ffffff; 
  text-decoration: none; 
 } 
 button.button-success { 
  /color: #4dd865; */
   border-color: #4dd865; 
 } 
 button.button-success:hover { 
   background: #4dd865; 
 } 
 button.button-error { 
   color: #ff3b30; 
  border-color: #ff3b30; 
 } 
 button.button-error:hover { 
   background: #ff3b30; 
 } 

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 430px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: -150px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 9999px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.modal.active {
  display: block;
}
.modal header {
  position: relative;
}
.modal h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
.modal .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.pull-right {
  float: right;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-family: circle;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: inherit;
  -webkit-text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  -moz-text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  -ms-text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  -o-text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="userdata" rules="groups" style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <thead>

                <tr>
                        <th> </th>
                        <th>EmployeeNum</th>
                        <th>EmployeeName</th>
                        <th>ChargeNum</th>
                        <th>Hours</th>
                </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>

        </tbody>
</table>

 <div class="modal">

    <header>
     
  <button class="close toggleModal">Close</button>
    </header>

    <section>
      <p>To approve the timesheet and submit it to WAM press "Approve", to decline the timesheet for later viewing press "Disapprove"</p>
    </section>

    <button class="button-border button-success toggleModal approve">
      <span class="icon"></span> Approve </button>

    <button class="button-border button-error pull-right toggleModal disapprove">
      <span class="icon"> < </span> Disapprove </button>
                <!-- <script> $(docuemnt).ready(function(){ -->
                        <!-- var rowCount = $('table#tableId tr:#a').index() + 1; -->
                        <!-- $("#a").style.color = "red"}); -->
                        <!-- </script> -->

  </div>
```

Please remove the **JSON data** with **getJSON**.

Comment: The output in the snippet is what I need. But for me I am having a hard time implementing the code you provided, as the table is not being populated with data

Comment: @Durango ... Are you getting any error in browser console??? Please console the data in the getJSON Ajax call...